# Will my Canon 500D with 18-55mm lens kit fit in a Crumpler Jimmy Bo 300 case?

Tags: camera-bag, kit-lens, canon-500d

Someone recommended Crumpler camera bags to me, I've just bought a Canon 500D with the standard (18-55mm) lens kit.

I want to the bag to be as small as possible. Crumpler says this one is for a SLR and short lens:

http://www.crumpler.co.uk/?product=Jimmy_Bo_300&page=details&product_line=843

I'm not sure if my lens qualifies as "short". Is anyone using this bag with a similar Canon? Does it fit and still protect the camera?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the product shots actually uses a Canon body:
[image: Product shot]

the kit lens is also one of the shortest in the current product line (the only one that is physically smaller that I can think of is the 50/1.8; so I would expect it to fit. Of course, it is always worth visiting your local friendly retailer if you're unsure about ordering online.

Comment: excellent, thanks - I knew the body would fit - i was just worried about the lens.

Comment: As a follow up - I bought the bag and the 18-55 lens fits fine.  I can even fit my zoom lens in there at a squeeze.